# Where are my monitoring metrics in Iguazio?

Tags: monitoring, mlops, nuclio, mlrun

Iguazio is supposed to be monitoring models and also resource metrics across the cluster like resource usage per pod / service, etc. When I open up the grafana service I only see a few pre-built dashboards for model monitoring and nuclio functions but nothing at the cluster level. Do I have to create my own dashboards for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually different grafana dashboards being used in Iguazio. The grafana dashboard you are referring to is for the platform users and is found on the services page. This includes all your model monitoring dashboards as you mentioned.
There is another grafana service that is used by the Iguazio system which comes pre-installed. You can access it by navigating to the Clusters page, under the Application tab, Status Dashboard column there is an icon that is a link which takes you to that grafana service. See this screenshot:
[image]
There you will find about 15 dashboards related to kubernetes, NGINX, GPUs, Nuclio, and Iguazio services resources monitoring. This constitutes the "cluster-level" monitoring that you were referring to.